# Use sed in bash to replace string with heredoc

Tags: bash, sed

In a bash script I need to replace a placeholder string in a file with some heredoc. How do I do that?

e.g. `sed -i 's/PLACEHOLDER_TEXT/$HEREDOC/g' > file.txt` where

```
<<HEREDOC
Some multiple
lines of
text to replace PLACEHOLDER_TEXT
HEREDOC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass trhough a temporary file and avoid a substitute due to behavior of replace pattern special char that can occur (like `&`,`\x`)

so

```
cat > /tmp/HereFile <<HEREDOC
Some multiple
lines of
text to replace PLACEHOLDER_TEXT
HEREDOC

sed '/PLACEHOLDER_TEXT/ {
   r /tmp/HereFile
   d
   }' YourFile
rm /tmp/HereFile
```

Answer (score 3):

Just flatten it out (you can change the # if that may appear in your data) and put the newlines back in afterward like:

```
sed "s/PLACEHOLDER_TEXT/$(echo "$HEREDOC"|tr "\n" "#")/g;s/#/\n/g" file.txt
```

To build the $HEREDOC variable:

```
$> export HEREDOC=$(cat<<EOF

    > what is going 
    > on with 
    > this 
    > thing
    > EOF
    > )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
val=$(tr '\n' ' ' < PlaceHolderText.txt); sed "s/PLACEHOLDER/$val/" File.txt
```

Example:

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat PlaceHolderText.txt
Some multiple
lines of
text to replace

sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat File.txt
This is a text with PLACEHOLDER for some additional data.

sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ val=$(tr '\n' ' ' < PlaceHolderText.txt); echo $val; sed "s/PLACEHOLDER/$val/" File.txt
This is a text with Some multiple lines of text to replace  for some additional data.
```

Comment: You should not use old an outdated back-tics, use parentheses like this: `val=$(tr .....)`